# Arduino Mega ADK connecting to JellyBean Android

Tags: android, arduino, adk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have had the most frustrating time trying to connect Arduino Mega ADK board to a JellyBean (Android 4.1.1) tablet.  The USB  host library from Android ADK does not work for the Arduino Mega ADK board, and the alternative library ArduinoADK-beta-001 from  http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/AccessoryMode  does not seem to be available any more (link broken as of November 2013).

I managed to compile some sample sketches on the Arduino Mega ADK using the modified ADK library by **circuitsathome.com**, which is available from Github at https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0, but the board then does not communicate with the 4.1.1. Android tablet. Specifically, the tablet recognized that the USB has been connected, but could not communicate with the board. Probable reason being that the JellyBean uses version 2 of the ADK protocol, which is not supported by the USB host library.

I have following questions:
1) has **anyone suceeded** in connecting the Arduino Mega ADK board with a JellyBean Android device?

2) If yes, which arduino libraries have been used? Where can I currently find the ArduinoADK-beta-001 (or it's successor).

Any feedback is highly appreciated, Ondrej Votava

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late. But this might help. I had similar issues for the past few weeks connecting and communicating the mega adk and Android. 
 
As I got succeeded now, I wrote blog posts which might help you and others with similar issues. I did run the application on Kitkat and Lollipop without any issues, but not sure about Jellybean. 
 
Here are few changes that are to be made to make the android application work on most of the devices.
 
Change **import com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory;** 
 to 
 **import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;**

Change **UsbAccessory accessory = UsbManager.getAccessory(intent);** 
 to 
 
**UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory)               intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);**

And Here is the link to the blog post http://blog.srichakram.in/2015/09/arduino-mega-adk-and-android.html